# clear file selection when press on blank area in Qtreeview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

Im using QFileSystemModel and QTreeView in my application(Pyqt5). I was looking for a way which I can clear file selection when press on the white blank area... to be more specific im need a way to know how to check whether the user press on the blank area in order to not choose at any file.

Comment: Well you would have to capture that click event which means making sure you capture it in the correct area -- once you have that and the information from it that should drive most of the rest of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to detect the click with an event filter and then determine if a valid QModelIndex is associated, and in the case of the empty area it is not associated with a QModelIndex:

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

        self.view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        path = CURRENT_DIR

        self.model.setRootPath(path)
        self.view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(path))

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            obj is self.view.viewport()
            and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick
        ):
            ix = self.view.indexAt(event.pos())
            if not ix.isValid():
                print("empty area")
                self.view.clearSelection()
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked right away, appreciate that!